# Android: invert RecyclerView positions

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm setting a RecyclerView behaving like a list, I want a button in the bottom of the list that when clicked adds more views, I'm thinking the easier way to do it is to make the position 0 as the first one in the bottom, and increasing the position to the top, so I can add views when the the view in position 0 is clicked.
If there is a better aproach for this problem do share.

**Here is my adapter:**

```
public class AddEventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddEventsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   public List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();



    public void addItem(String name) {
        notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
        items.add(name);

    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, items.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_event_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setData(position);
        holder.eventName.setText(i + "");
        if(position == 0)
        {
            holder.theLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7F9099"));
            holder.eventName.setText("Add");
        }

    }


    static int i;
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView eventName;
        public RelativeLayout theLayout;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            eventName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
            theLayout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundevent);

            theLayout.setId(++i);


        }

        public void setData(final int position) {
            theLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (position == items.size() - 1) {
                        addItem("");
                    } else {
                        removeItem(position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }


}
```

You may notice some errors in that, I've been over it for the last 10 hours and I'm having a logic breakdown

Comment: Why not add a button outside the RecyclerView, either above or below it, so it's always visible regardless of scroll?

Comment: I tried that, but it looks really weird when scrolling down

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's solved by addind this line to the LayoutManager `.setReverseLayout(true);`

Answer (score 1):

you can add a footer view at the end of the list and inside that you can add your button. This is the link to create a footer in recycler view https://github.com/u3breeze/android-RecyclerView-WithHeaderAndFooter. You can add the views in the normal way

Comment: Okay I want to use it, but it's not functioning properly, have you used it?

Comment: If you want a footer or header, you don't need any libraries. Just update your adapter to return the count + 1 (for the footer/header), and then in the onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder functions simply check the position and if it is 0 (for header) or count (for footer) display your button.

Comment: Meanwhile I gave the library a try and it works perfectly, an issue still remains, when a view is removed all the views go up, I need to set thhe views's gravity to bottom, or invert the count of the adapter positions